# For any point outside of a circle, is there ever only one tangent to the circle that passes through the point?

Tags: circles

For any point outside of a circle, is there ever only one tangent to the circle that passes through the point?  Are there ever more than two such tangents? (I cannot find the exact answer i need through the other question answered. My question does not involve any actual numbers and equations. It's hard for me to find the answer within that question. ) Thank you!

Comment: always exactly two tangents through any external point

Comment: Please don’t repost the same question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two such tangents, in fact. No more, no less. And the points on which the tangents meet the circle, the centre of the circle, and the points from which the tangents were drawn are concyclic